# Takes 2 different random number in C language

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [calling rand() returning non-random results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686271/calling-rand-returning-non-random-results)

In my workshop I need to takes 2 different random numbers but I get 2 same random number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int random1_6(){
 int k;
 srand(time(0));
 k=((rand()%6)+1);
 return k;
}
int main(void){
 int a,b;
    a=random1_6();
    printf("%d.\n",a);
    b=random1_6();
    printf("%d.\n",b);
return 0;
}
```

How to get 2 different random number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A non-cryptographic random number generator (RNG) is not truely random but it generates random-like numbers based on a seed.

What you do is initializing the RNG with the same seed two times, so you get the same results. Seed the RNG just once, e.g. at program start, and you will get random-like different results.

Edit: a code like follows should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int random1_6(){
  return ((rand() % 6) + 1);
}

int main(void){
  int a,b;
  srand(time(NULL));

  a = random1_6();
  printf("%d.\n",a);

  b=random1_6();
  printf("%d.\n",b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what is going on.

Comment: Can you edit my code to get diiferent result?

Comment: @Conan9x1111 edited answer and added example

Comment: @Conan9x1111 It may be, since a value range from 1 to 6 is not very big. When I execute the code above I get sometimes two times the same value and some times different values. That's how random works.

Comment: Thank you! Your code is usefull.

Comment: If we need sum of two different random number is 11, it takes 218504 times call 2 random numbers. Can you have effective way?

Comment: Generate a random number and subtract it from 11 to get your second number?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do `srand(time(0));` on every call. **Only call it once.**

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the random number generator seed with `srand()` only **once** : upon each call you are re-initializing the RNG with the same seed since is it most likely that the two subsequent calls to `time(0)` will return the same timestamp (seconds-level precision), hence rand() will return the same number twice.

If you call `srand()` only once at the beginning of your program (in the `main()` entry-point), then every call to rand() will return a different number.

Answer (score 0):

You always initialize the random number generator with the same seed, so you'll get the same random sequence, it is pseudo random anyway. Typically you will only want to call srand once in the beginning to initialize the generator.

Also, you only have 6 different possible outcomes, so it is perfectly legitimate to get same number twice, there is 1/6 chance for that.