# Program Not Returning Results as Expected. Probably Misuse of "bool"?

Tags: c, random, srand

I'm new to programming and I had to work on a program that would simulate 10,000 games of craps. I got it to calculate points for house and player just fine until I added in the function "diceRoll" where player rolls again and again until it matches the first roll or 7 (house wins). Now it gives decidedly not random results (such as the house winning 0 times out of 10,000). What did I do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool diceRoll (int a)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL));
    int n = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(n < 1) {
        b = rand() % 12;
        if(b == a || b == 6) n++;
    }
    if(b == 6) return false;
    else return true;
}


int main (void)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL));
    int a, n, house, player, point;
    house = 0;
    player = 0;
    point = 0;

    for(n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        a = rand() % 12;
        if(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 11) {
            house++;
        }
        else if(a == 6 || a == 10) {
            player++;
        }
        else {
            if(diceRoll(a) == true) player++;
            else house++;
        }
    }

    printf("The house has %i points.\n", house);
    printf("The player has %i points.\n", player);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've fallen into the trap of overseeding, which is just as bad as not seeding. You only have to seed a given random number generator once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling rand() returning non-random results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686271/calling-rand-returning-non-random-results)

Comment: You would do well to [read this article](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html) concerning why you're about to load your dice-game to a statistically non-uniform distribution due to the side effects of `rand()` - modulo weighting. Better you find out now rather than later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've over-seeded, remove the call to `srand()` in `diceRoll` and you should be fine (this ignores [bias due to modulo usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator)).

Comment: I updated my answer to include the link for a why modulo bias exists, stated much more eloquently than I could.

Comment: I understand bias. I don't get overseed.

Comment: @zubergu if you want the meat behind *why* things aren't what they may seem [see this document](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html)

Comment: IIRC, seeding multiple times within the same second will produce the same result over and over again.

Comment: @zubergu: seems backwards, but fair enough! Every time you seed a random number generator, it starts from scratch. It doesn't take long to seed it, so using `time(NULL)` as the argument would be like calling `srand(4)` in a tight loop. Constantly reseeding causes constant sorrow.

Comment: user7116 @WhozCraig Now I get it. Put it all together in complete answer and it's a +1 from me for another lesson learned.

Comment: @zubergu: this question is a duplicate of a question which answers it just fine. I voted to close and made my answer community wiki so I would receive no reputation. All points should go to the answerers of the original.

Answer (score 0):

Only seed in `main()` (and not in a loop) and don't seed it in the `diceRoll(a)` function.

I ran it your way and got `house = 2, player = 9998`.

Removing the `srand((unsigned)time(null));` in the `diceroll(a)` came back with:

`The house has 5435 points`

`The player has 4565 points`

I assume that is what you wanted

```
bool diceRoll (int a)
{
    int n = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while(n < 1) {
        b = rand() % 12;
        if(b == a || b == 6) n++;
    }
    if(b == 6) return false;
    else return true;
}

int main (void)
{
    srand( (unsigned)time(NULL));
    int a, n, house, player, point;
    house = 0;
    player = 0;
    point = 0;

    for(n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        a = rand() % 12;
        if(a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 11) {
            house++;
        }
        else if(a == 6 || a == 10) {
            player++;
        }
        else {
            if(diceRoll(a) == true) player++;
            else house++;
        }
    }

    printf("The house has %i points.\n", house);
    printf("The player has %i points.\n", player);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are giving a solution without explaining why it was wrong to do it his way.