# c++ random doesn't work(returns same value always)

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << rand()%30<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code and always get 11. Please explain why if you know. I use latest codeblocks and c++

Comment: Thank you for responces
I thought that random work as in Java : )
such mistake...
    srand(time(0));
    cout << rand() % 30<< endl;
works well

Comment: int getRandomNumber() {return 11;}
:D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`rand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/srand.html) function does not generate a truly random number; it actually returns the next [pseudo-random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) value in a sequence of values ranging from `0` to `RAND_MAX`. You can change the starting point in that sequence using [`srand()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/srand.html).

A common technique is to [initialise `srand()` using the current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574914/srandtimenull-doesnt-change-seed-value-quick-enough) using the [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/time.html) function, [as shown below](http://codepad.org/9VhlViwp):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("%d", rand());
  return 0;
}
```

This causes the program to start generating numbers from a different point in the sequence every time it is run, making it appear to be less predictable.

Answer (score 3):

To initialize the random number generator, you need to call `srand()` with a seed.

You only need to initialize it [once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once).

You will get the same sequence of numbers with the same seed, so normally, people use the current time as seed as that is pretty much guaranteed to change between program executions:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

`rand()` is an older random number generator, inherited from C. C++ has better RNG's available. Just use the [`std::default_random_engine`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) if you don't want to worry about details.

Also, `%30` reduces random-ness. You probably want a `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,30)` there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the random number generator to get different number set in each time call it, you should definitely use with time.h. 
Include time.h below the  then use like this;

```
srand(time(NULL));

printf("%d", rand());
```

Comment: Include time.h below iostream