# Generate two different random numbers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to generate two different random numbers in C within a given range.The range is

```
0 to nk-1
```

But my following code sometimes works and sometimes fails.What is the reason behind this?

```
n1=rand()%nk;
n2=rand()%nk;
while(n1==n2)
{
 srand(time(0));
 n2=rand()%nk;
}
```

Comment: `srand()` should be called only once to seed the random generator. Do not call it inside the while loop !

Comment: The canonical duplicate is: [`srand()`: why call it only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once/).

Comment: If you like to generate two different random numbers in that range you should use 

    n1 = rand()%nk;
    n2 = rand()%(nk-1);
    if(n1 == n2) n2 += 1;

You should avoid the while loop.

Comment: I don't see that this is a duplicate (given that he states in a comment, that he get's a segmentation fault). He should clarify what "fails" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
srand(time(0));
```

This has to be outside `loop`.

In loop you reseed the RNG , whereas you should be doing it once.

Comment: I moved it outside the loop,but this only increased the probability of successful running.Meaning that program is still seg faulting but less as compared to my code.

Comment: @Dante.  Is this your excat code.

Comment: Yes it is my exact code.

Comment: @Dante.: The segfault is somewhere else in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 3):

You're supposed to seed the RNG once,

```
srand(time(0));
n1=rand()%nk;
n2=rand()%nk;
while(n1==n2)
{
 n2=rand()%nk;
}
```

Comment: Cool,now its working.Can you please throw some light on the reason.Explanation would be great.

Comment: Take a look at the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574914/srandtimenull-doesnt-change-seed-value-quick-enough).

Comment: I am sorry ,I only ran it 4 to 5 times. But when I ran it for 12 th time still segmentation fault. I don't think it correct.

Comment: @Dante. The segmentation fault is occurring somewhere else. I suggest you run it through a debugger to determine the cause.