# rand() does not update values between function invocations

Tags: c

I noticed that if I used `rand()` to generate random values inside a loop, it will change the value at each iteration. However, this is not the case between for function invocations even by seeding via `srand()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> 

void test(){   
    float r;

    srand(time(NULL));
    r =  (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    printf(" %6.3f \n",r);
}  
int main(){

     float r;
    //srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        test();
        //r =  (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        //printf(" %6.3f \n",r);
    }

}
```

How can I force rand() to refresh its values in each function call?

Comment: Seed once per program, only. Move `srand` into `main` as one of the first lines (not inside a loop!). I can see from your commented-out line that you intended this at some point.

Comment: Hmmm I apologize for this silly question. You are right. I should've been more careful

Comment: @MicroVirus you should add an answer with that, it will likely help others that try to use `rand()`

Comment: The most important reason though is that in debug mode the (VC2008) compiler wants the randomizer to be deterministic and thus always seeds it with he same value, even when calling `time()` (otherwise here would have been different outcomes, even when calling `srand` multiple times).

Comment: @Cristik Sure, done.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie That's not true. It's just that the loop only runs 5 times and the `time()` function doesn't have the resolution to change within such a minuscule amount of time.

Comment: Here's a more detailed answer: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574914/srandtimenull-doesnt-change-seed-value-quick-enough)

Answer (score 1):

Seed once per program, only. Move `srand` into `main` as one of the first lines (not inside a loop!). I can see from your commented-out line that you intended this at some point.