# c++ srand() not working

Tags: c++, srand

I  didn't understand what everyone said here: [srand(time(NULL)) doesn't change seed value quick enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574914/srandtimenull-doesnt-change-seed-value-quick-enough)
 and I am supposed to use the srand() to generate a different random number every time but I keep getting the same number, any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, num;
    cout<<"Enter the number:\n";
    cout<<"n= "<<n<<endl;
    cin>>num;
     srand(time(NULL));
    n= rand()%10+1;

    if(n==num)
        cout<<"win\n";
    else
        cout<<"lose\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What number are you getting everytime?

Comment: `cout<<"n= "<<n<<endl;` is done before `n` is initialized.

Comment: I'm getting 0 everytime

Comment: @Amal - how do you know that? Add a `print of `n` after `n= rand()%10+1;` instead of before as it is now.

Comment: I fixed the mistake thank you

Comment: If that fixed your problem, you should accept the answer from @MohitJain so peoble can see that the question is solved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<"n= "<<n<<endl;
```

Here are you printing `n` before initialization that exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution**
Print it after `n= rand()%10+1;`

Answer (score 0):

`srand(int)` shakes numbers depends on the value passed by the argument. If you give the same number, the random numbers will be the same.
In your URL, people call `srand(time(NULL))` twice but the clock of the computer did not had the time to change between the two calls. So the random numbers are the same.